# Bootstrap 4 Grid System Mismatch

Tags: bootstrap-4, grid-layout, bootstrap-grid

I am trying to achieve something like this:
[image]

The code I wrote for this follows:

```
                  <div class="col-md-7">
                        <!-- Donor Name -->
                        <div class="md-form">
                            <i class="fas fa-user prefix red-text"></i>
                            <input type="text" name="donorname" class="form-control">
                            <label for="donorname">Donor's Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <!-- Blood Group -->
                                <div class="md-form">
                                    <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="bloodgroup">
                                      <option value="0">Select Blood Group</option>
                                      <option value="1">A +</option>
                                      <option value="2">A -</option>
                                      <option value="3">B +</option>
                                      <option value="4">B -</option>
                                      <option value="5">AB +</option>
                                      <option value="6">AB -</option>
                                      <option value="7">O +</option>
                                      <option value="8">O -</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <!-- DOB -->
                                <div class="md-form">
                                    <i class="fas fa-calendar prefix red-text"></i>
                                    <input placeholder="Selected date" type="date" name="donordob" class="form-control datepicker">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <!--Textarea with icon prefix-->
                        <div class="md-form">
                            <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt prefix"></i>
                            <textarea id="form10" class="md-textarea form-control" rows="2"></textarea>
                            <label for="form10">Medical Issues</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

But, somewhere it seems to mis match and the 2nd Parent column `Medical Issue` seems to go down. 
Can anybody suggest, where did I go wrong?

ANy suggestion would help

Answer (score 1):

*Bootstrap* is using 12 column grid system. So if your columns add up more than 12, each group of extra columns will wrap into a new line:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#column-wrapping

So the fix for your problem is just to change the parent column from `.col-md-6` to `.col-md-5`:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <!--Textarea with icon prefix-->
        <div class="md-form">
            <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt prefix"></i>
            <textarea id="form10" class="md-textarea form-control" rows="2"></textarea>
            <label for="form10">Medical Issues</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/9brxyau8/2/

Comment: You are right. I got confused while arranging them.